# Naming list items with a data frame?

Tags: r

This seems like it should be easy, but apparently it isn't. I have a list of dataframes (dflist), 12 of them, and I have a character vector with 12 names (thenames, looks like c("A", "B", "C", "D", etc.).

This seems like it should work:

```
names(dflist) <- thenames
```

However, it names the entire first list object as c("A","B","C")... etc. instead of renaming the first dataframe A, the second dataframe, B, etc.

What's the correct way to apply this?

Comment: Have you tried `set_names` from package `rlang`? `set_names(dflist, thenames)`

Comment: I haven't; when I run it, I get this odd error (verifying that both the vector and the list are the same length):

Error: `nm` must be `NULL` or a character vector the same length as `x`

Comment: I don't what data you are using, but a minimal example would be `dflist <- list(cars, cars, cars)` and then `dflist <-  rlang::set_names(dflist, c("A", "B", "C"))`

Comment: Can you include a reproducible example? I cannot recreate output.

Comment: Please set up a reproducible example with sample data that we can run in empty R environment to recreate your issue. Even post: `str(dfList)`.